# dereferencing "void *" pointer -- list in a list

Tags: c, linked-list, void-pointers

I want to write a program with lists in lists. 
So there is the list.h file :

```
typedef struct node {
    void *ptr;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} NODE;

typedef struct list {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    int size;
    char name[MAX_SIZE_NAME];
} LIST;
```

At first I have the list, for example list_.
Now i allocate 5 elements.

And in every node I want to allocate a new list.
I tryed with this code :

```
if (list_->head->next == list_->tail) {
    list_ins_next(list_);
    ptr = list_->tail->prev;
    ptr->ptr = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    ptr->ptr->head = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

Sorry I dont have so much programming experience, but it would be great if you would help me

the error is : dereferencing 'void *' pointer

Comment: What is `node::ptr` meant to represent? Is it meant to always point to the containing `struct list` or be an arbitrary data-store?

Comment: Also if you're using `void*` you're probably doing something wrong (because you're giving up type-safety).

Answer (score 2):

```
ptr->ptr->head = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

is equivalent to:

```
(*(ptr->ptr)).head = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

The expression `*(ptr->ptr)` is not valid since you can't dereference a `void*`.

You need a pointer of type `LIST*` to dereference it and then use the `head` member of the object.

Use:

```
((LIST*)ptr->ptr)->head = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```